# FieldType by dbxSqlite driver always ftWideMemo only when the dataset is empty

Tags: delphi, dbexpress, delphi-xe4

using delphi xe4 and dbexpress on sqllite3

This issue occurs only when the dataset is empty.

1. Create an app with TClientDataSet, TDataSetProvider and TSQLQuery and TSQLConnection.
2. The TSQLConnection must be of drivername Sqlite.
3. After opening of the TClientDataSet, DataType of all the FieldDefs is shown as ftWideMemo!!!

This is only when the dataset is empty. When dataset is filled with 1 or more records, the FieldTypes are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get around this problem by adding a record with ID=-1 to my tables, so the table wont be empty anymore and then in application I ignore records with ID==-1 when populating data.